# Collaborative project: How do we feel about licensing?

Tags: discussion, csw-project

Over in the [Collaborative project's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17796/collaborative-shared-worlds), we've been making some progress with the project to create free worlds for anyone to use.

We've found a point that's hard to agree on - licence - as in what licence fits the project best. Some suggestions have been:

- CC-BY-SA (the licence used by SE)
  This allows us to freely ask questions and use content from here, but restricts the licensing options *(previously spelled 'potions'...)* for users of our work.
- CC-BY
  This licence seems to fit our desired outcomes (that anyone can use, in any way, and licence their work how they see fit) the best, but means we can't use content from here without asking post authors for explicit permission to use CC-BY.

We're now looking for opinions from all our contributors and potential contributors about this subject. What licence should we use, and why should we use it?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but note that the license only applies to the *content*, not the *ideas or facts* underpinning that content. So you are, in principle, free to *take what you have learned*, rewrite it in your own words, and license the result however you feel like. (That said, regardless of license, if a particular contributor's insights were instrumental in what you came up with, crediting that contributor as you would had you used the CC-BY-SA content verbatim might not be a bad idea.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling indeed. I think we felt that that was slightly unfair to post authors: there is some expectation that by-sa is the license used. We'd want to get permission to use cc-by instead.

Comment: Again, for the content yes, CC-BY-SA is the license that anything on the Stack Exchange network is licensed under. So if you use something verbatim as it was posted, you'd have to do it under that license *or* ask for specific permission to use it under a different license. But I think much of what gets posted on the main site at least, would probably be more useful as ideas than as verbatim content, in which case the content license doesn't really apply. I still feel crediting the author of the content for the idea used is a good thing, though; at the very worst, it cannot hurt.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling definitely; I think we're agreed on attributing/crediting authors.